# Delete Outlook 365 Calendar Event Through API

Tags: php, api, outlook

I am trying to delete a calendar event through the REST API and it is returning a 400 error.

The `DELETE` url:

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/events/AQMkADA...URF1shGWDYAAAIBDQAAAOVip_uuQf5ApURF1shGWDYAAAAwSb9FAAAA
```

The call is generated in PHP using this [code sample](https://dev.office.com/code-samples-detail/2138).

```
$delete_url = $outlookApiUrl . $outlook_id;
$response = $this->makeApiCall($this->access_token, $this->email, 'DELETE', $delete_url);
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL was missing a "Me" 
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Me/events/AQMkADA...